# While handling an NServiceBus message, is it possible to peek at the input queue?

Tags: nservicebus

I have a Windows service using NServiceBus to handle incoming messages.
While processing a message, I would like to check to see if there are any other remaining messages on the queue to process.
What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Scott out of curiosity why do you care if other messages are on the queue?

Comment: I have a handler that converts the messages into rows of a spreadsheet, for uploading into a legacy system. (one message = one row). I don't want to move the spreadsheet to the upload folder until there are no more messages on the queue. i.e. I want to upload a single big spreadsheet, not 1000's of 1 row spreadsheets.

Comment: Another way to handle this would be to "ticket" each message for example 1 of 10, 2 of 10 etc. This would obviously have to be done on the sender's side.

Comment: thanks hugh, but in this case there are multiple senders, each unaware of each other. Appreciate your suggestion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific scenario I'd say that a saga could be appropriate where it is created by the first message received, opens a timeout (for let's say one minute), collects all messages during that period of time, then Bus.SendLocal's a message containing all rows, for which another handler creates the spreadsheet and uploads.

Comment: This sounds like excellent advice, thank you. However, even within a saga, it would be useful to know if there were any more messages on the queue. In this system, messages arrive in batches, several thousand at a time, and then none for hours. Ideally I don't want to start the spreadsheet creation and upload until I have collected all the messages from the bus from that batch.
Any suggestions on peeking at the queue? Or is that just a really bad idea for some reason?

Comment: Then you can have the saga check in its timeout method if it has received any messages since the last timeout, and only then send the information.

Answer (score 1):

Since, `NServiceBus` is using `MSMQ`, you can use the methods from `System.Messaging`.
Included is a modified method, I'm currently working on, to do a kind of batch processing.

```
using System.Messaging;

public int PeekAtQueue()
{
    const string QUEUE_NAME = "private$\\you_precious_queuname";

    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(".\\" + QUEUE_NAME))
        return 0;

    var messageQueues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(Environment.MachineName);
    var queue = messageQueues.Single(x => x.QueueName == QUEUE_NAME);
    return queue.GetAllMessages().Count();
}
```

Modified here itself in the editor. Hope it still compiles :)
Found a similar discussion here, by the way:

http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/counting-messages-in-an-msmq-messagequeue-from-c/